# Profiling ros_controllers with Valgrind / Callgrind

Tags: gazebo, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to proifle my controllers written in the ros_control framework in Gazebo. To this end, I added the following argument in gazebo_ros/launch/empty_world.launch:

`launch-prefix="valgrind --tool=callgrind --callgrind-out-file=/home/user/callgrind.out"`

However, no output file is produced. Has anybody who tried profiling ROS controllers using the Valgrind/Callgrind toolchain a solution for this?

Thanks,

-Robert-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275458/profiling-ros_controllers-with-valgrind-/-callgrind/) by [Robert Krug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1269/robert-krug/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2017-11-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This scould be duplicates of https://answers.ros.org/question/28383/time-consumption-profiling/ and also look at
http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Profiling%20roslaunch%20nodes

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2018-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0